# Replace text inside double quotation marks using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to replace a lot of lines that would otherwise take so much time.

In this case, I need

```
"Test": "Test1"
```

to become:

```
"Test": "Test2"
```

I tried a lot of code. Couldn't find something that does exactly what I need. The only code I could find that almost does what I need is:

Find:

```
"Test": "[^"]*\K
```

Replace:

```
_Test2
```

The issues with this code, is that it becomes

```
"Test": "Test1Test2"
```

instead of

```
"Test": "Test2"
```

Help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: You should give more details. As it is, you can simply find : `"Test": "Test1"` and replace it with `"Test": "Test2"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misplaced the match reset operator, use:

- Find what: `"Test": "\K[^"]*`
- Repace with: `Test2`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This one works :)

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I replace text inside double quotation marks

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `"([A-Za-z]*)(\d{1,1})"`
- Set "Replace with" to `"\1"`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

**Before**:

```
"Test": "Test1"
```

**After**:

```
"Test": "Test"
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)